# SQL Server 2012 FileTable mapped to a mounted S3 Virtual Directory

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-s3, filestream, filetable

Is it possible to mount an Amazon S3 virtual directory on the machine that handles an Sql Server 2012 database for the purpose of mapping that virtual directory into a filetable in Sql server?  What I'm hoping is to take advantage of S3 but use the ease of the filestream capabilities of sql server 2012 to manage user uploaded files.

I got the idea as a derivative of this site http://cloudcomputing.sys-con.com/node/1645639 where I saw that you could mount an S3 directory in windows.  However, my intention is to not backup my sql server database in such a mounted folder, but to reference that folder in a filestream table and be able to have files that are saved in this table be referenced in amazon's cdn later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this post [FILESTREAM/FILETABLE Clarifications for Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644623/filestream-filetable-clarifications-for-implementation?rq=1)

I think that a virtual directory pointing to S3 would be enough to trick SQL server's filetable feature.